# click event for dynamic generated buttons

Tags: android

hi  i am generating buttons dynamically in which i want to implement click event for each button .how can i do this

Comment: Show your code, then we can show you how to add an OnClickListener @Rajath's answer is correct, unless your code is extremely ..different

Answer (score 1):

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //your code here
        }
    })
```

Comment: when i am doing this the last button generated dynamically only perform this click event.

Comment: Then you should share your code of buttons generation and registration to listeners.

Comment: I have many dynamic buttons in my app..n how to put click event on all buttons..Then how to put this.